# Select Analysis Invalid Expression

Tags: arcpy, sql, select, null, error-000358

I am attempting to select nulls from an in_memory feature layer using Arcpy's Select_analysis. Code example below, as well as, various iterations of attempts to alter the SQL query with no success.

```
sql_1 = '"{}_BBL" IS NOT NULL'.format(some_dataset_name)
print(sql_1)
arcpy.Select_analysis("Some_inmemory_layer", "Output_Name", sql_1)
```

The actual SQL query itself is as follows:

```
'"E_GIS_20190111_BBL" IS NOT NULL'
```

The empty output Feature Class yielded when encountering the invald expression error shows that the field name I am referencing is correct (field name matches above used in query in both attrib table and properties>fields tab).

I have tried the following fixes with no success:

```
'"E_GIS_20190111_BBL" <> NULL'

'"E_GIS_20190111_BBL" != NULL'
```

Error message received:

> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression 
>   "E_GIS_20190111_BBL" IS NOT NULL
>   Failed to execute (Select).

Comment: Your workspace is set to in_memory? Try: `sql_1 = "{0} IS NOT NULL".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(some_dataset_name,'{0}_BBL'.format(some_dataset_name)))`

Comment: Try this SQL query instead? `"E_GIS_20190111_BBL IS NOT NULL"`, note it is  just double quotes.

Comment: BERA - Thank you for the reply. I attempted to use your revised sql expression and got back the same invald expression error.
Hornbydd - Thank you for the reply. I attempted this, as well, and got back the same invalid expression error

Comment: The easiest way to determine the where_clause formatting is to run the command manually. In Geoprocessing, Results, "Copy as Python snippet". Paste the code in a text editor.